# ClickHouse - Understanding Query Profiler

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to understand the query execution in ClickHouse codebase. My question is focussed on click house development and I am new to it.

The query_id is always missing from the trace_log table. -Was able to solve this , please read below for EDIT 1.

I come to know [Sample Query Profiler](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/optimizing-performance/sampling-query-profiler/) which can trace the execution by aggregating results from system.trace_log table.

**What I have done so far ?**

I have

```
SET allow_introspection_functions = 1
SET query_profiler_cpu_time_period_ns=10000000
SET query_profiler_real_time_period_ns=10000000
```

after logging into **clickhouse-client**. -  is this the right way to set this and other properties mentioned [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-allow_introspection_functions). ?

Is there any other way to understand code flow when the queries are executed?

[image]

**EDIT 1**

I was able to get the query_id in system.trace_log table after setting

```
SET query_profiler_cpu_time_period_ns=1
SET query_profiler_real_time_period_ns=1
```

1. As you can see that I am setting a very low value of 1 for profiling real-time and CPU, is it the right approach?
2. Furthermore, when I try to use the following query for different **query_id but same SQL query** I get different results in output. I am not able to understand this, please explain.

   SELECT
           count(),
           arrayStringConcat(arrayMap(x -> concat(demangle(addressToSymbol(x)), '\n    ', addressToLine(x)), trace), '\n') AS sym
       FROM system.trace_log
       WHERE (query_id = 'PASTE_QUERY_ID') AND (event_date = today())
       GROUP BY trace
       ORDER BY count() DESC
       LIMIT 10